# Putting TV cables inside a plasterboard wall cavity - Is my plan reasonable?

Tags: drywall, television

I'm mounting my tv on the wall at the weekend and want all the cables hidden in the wall but easily accessible. I've found these backplates that I'm looking to use:

[image]

The plan is to cut out a section of plasterboard next to the wooden stud, attach a new stud section for the cables to fall down in to as the wall contains insulation material which would make it hard to run cables through, put one of these plates at the top and bottom, then put a new bit of plasterboard there, screw it on to the new stud and the existing one and plaster over it.

I've drawn up in AutoCAD before and after - legend:

- Green: Plasterboard
- Blue: Stud
- Red: TV
- Purple: VESA Mount
- Grey: Backboxes (I'll have to cut a section out of the bottom/top of the backbox to allow the cables through)

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

The only difficulties I see are:
- Screwing the new stud pieces in to place, half under the existing plasterboard. 
- There may be a noggin across at some point, which I'll have to cut and attach to my new stud.

Comment: How do you plan to bring mains AC power to the TV?  Or is it a 12V powered TV?

Comment: After other answers/comments, I'm going to spur off the sockets at the bottom on the right side and put one behind the TV

Answer (score 1):

I see no real reason to add in the new stud box to allow for the TV signal cables to have their own cavity. You should be able to simply mount the flange on oneside of the backbox to the stud and use some type of toggle anchor to simply attach the other flange of the box to the drywall. Using this technique you should be able to simply cut two holes in the existing plaster board without having to remove and replace a large amount of material.

I do see two concerns though:

1. It is not up to standard electrical codes to string TV power cords or extension cords up through a wall cavity like you can do with low voltage signal cables. You really should plan to install separate permanent in-wall mains wiring from the existing power outlet up to a new electrical box and outlet that you locate behind the TV.
2. From your pictures it looks like the TV mount that you are planning to use is one that mounts to only one stud. If that mount is an articulated arm type designed to allow the TV to fold out from the wall then I would strongly suggest that you look for another type of mount that installs across multiple studs. If the stud locations are not in a good location then face that wall section with 3/4 inch thick plywood that does span two to three studs and mount the bracket to that plywood.

Comment: The reason for the box is the cavity is full of insulation, so it would be very difficult to get cables through, they'd just get stuck. I also considered some kind of conduit but I couldn't find one that might be flexible enough to get down through the hole made through the plasterboard for the back box that is big enough to fit all the cables through.

Comment: 1. I didn't consider that - I will run a separate power outlet up next to the TV - It's probably best to keep them separated from the signal cables anyway.

2. What are your concerns with single stud TV mounts? The one I've purchased has thousands of verified reviews, I was a little uneasy at the idea initially.

Comment: Single stud mount brackets, in particular ones that have an articulating arm that permits the TV to hinge out from the wall, can place incredible torque on the mounting screws. Safety is always a concern but the simple fact that you have a mount over plaster board with screws that can then see flex is a recipe for the wall board to start to crumble and allow the bracket to come loose.

Comment: I see the concern. From what I've read, the stud should easily handle the weight and the bracket and screws provided are certified to handle a way heavier TV than mine (its 15kg). I will expose the stud and mount directly to it, so it will be tight in to the stud with no plasterboard.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, throwing data/signal cables down a wall cavity is a standard way to conceal cables for wall TVs.  Conduit optional, though in an insulated wall you will need it.  You'll want that insulation or else cold will just come sheeting off that wall.

Power cables, different story. You cannot toss a mains power cord down a wall cavity, nor can you intermix it in the same conduit with data cables or low-voltage cables.

Some TVs either run on low voltage, or are capable of running on low voltage. If that is under 55 watts, the low-voltage power cable can be tossed in the same passage as the data cables.  Otherwise, no.

The mains power cable must be run via standard wiring methods for mains power.

Some companies make kits which include both portals and a conduit tube between them.  Some kits also provide for the mains power, by including a receptacle at the top portal and an **inlet** at the bottom portal. You then use a short 3-prong extension cord to hop from the inlet to the surge suppressor power strip that your VCR, cable box etc. are plugged into.  Hold on, the 1980s just called and wants their "VCR" term back.  I mean your DVD pla- hold on, I'm getting another call - your Roku, Blu-Ray, Sling, what have you.